# Are "theme identification" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions asking for a specific theme or type of theme on-topic?
For example, this question: [What is this grey theme seen on the gooseberry website?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18214/599)

[GD.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification) has [font-identification](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification) questions which are similar, but they probably get more font identification questions than we ever will get in [theme-identification](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-identification) questions..

Should these kinds of questions be on-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider this off topic.

Font's are an essential part of graphic design, where as themes are pretty much tweaking application for your own personal preference.

You can always ask on other sites (non SE), and probably get an answer.